# Shared test resources for different projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have two projects that need the same test resources.
I'm using maven for dependency handling and eclipse for running the tests.
How can I share the test resources with maven without cloning them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the test resources in another project or Maven module and add a dependency to this project from the other two (scope `test` should work). 
The test resources in the new module/project should go in `src/main/resources` not in `src/test/resources` (I think, otherwise they'll be available only during the `test` goal of this project)